# Norms in the Space $NBV(\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So the space $NBV(\mathbb{R}$) is the space of bounded variation functions where  when $x \rightarrow -\infty$ then $ f(x) \rightarrow 0$. So we defined a norm that is $\| f\|=V_f(\mathbb{R})$. I think i proved that under this norm this is a banach space but if u guys have any ideas i would be glad to hear them.

But thats not the question , i would like to find an example where we have that $\| f_n -f\|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$ but $\| f_n -f\|$ does not converge to zero, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exactly $V_f(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Observe that 
\begin{align*}
|(f_n(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i+1}))-(f_n(x_{i})-f(x_{i}))|&\leq |f_n(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i+1})|+|f_n(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i+1})|\\
&\leq 2\lVert f_n-f\rVert_\infty
\end{align*}
The worst case is when those are tight (you should be able to find example where it is), in that case you are summing $p$ terms of the form of the LHS to get the total variation, so if $p>\frac{1}{\lVert f_n-f\rVert_\infty}$ for all $n$, then your total variation doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: what do you mean by tight?

Comment: You can find such values of $f$ and $f_n$ such that the above inequalities are actually equalities.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution functions involved with the De Moivre-Laplace theorem are convenient examples, where you have a sequence of discrete probability distributions converging weakly to a continuous distribution.  One can show in this case (by the Berry-Esseen theorem) that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty=O(1/\sqrt n)$ but of course $\|f_n-f\|=2$ for all $n$.

In particular, let $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t)dt$ where $\phi(t)=\exp(-t^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ and where $f_n$ is the cumulative distribution function of the random variable $(X_n-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ where $X_n$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $(p,n)$, that is, for which $P(X_n=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.  As with all cumulative probability distribution functions, they are in $\text{NBV}(\mathbb R)$ and $\|f\|=\|f_n\|=1$. Since $f_n$ is purely discrete and $f$ is continuous, $\|f-f_n\|=2$.
By the classical central limit theorem, however, $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.  (See the last displayed formula on the Wikipedia blurb about the [Classical CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT), or the [Berry Esseen Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) for this last claim.)

Comment: Im not familiar with that theorem , and the functions i saw associated with that theorem when i looked it up dont seem to be of bounded variation, can u tell me what functions you are thinking about?